# sum same column across multiple files using awk ?

Tags: awk

I want to add the 3rd column of 5 files such that the new file will have the same 2nd col and the sum of the 3rd col of the 5 files.

I tried something like this:

```
$ cat freqdat044.dat | awk '{n=$3; getline <"freqdat046.dat";print $2" " n+$3}' > freqtrial1.dat 

freqdat048.dat`enter code here`$ cat freqdat044.dat | awk '{n=$3; getline <"freqdat046.dat";print $2" " n+$3}' > freqtrial1.dat
```

The files names:

```
freqdat044.dat
freqdat045.dat
freqdat046.dat
freqdat047.dat 
freqdat049.dat
freqdat050.dat
```

And saved in output file the contain only `$2` and the new col form the summation of the 3rd

Comment: example input/output pls!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '{x[$2] += $3} END {for(y in x) print y,x[y]}' freqdat044.dat freqdat045.dat freqdat046.dat freqdat047.dat freqdat049.dat freqdat050.dat
```

This does not necessarily print lines as they appear in the first file.  If you want to preserve that sorting, then you have to save that ordering somewhere:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {keys[FNR]=$2; cnt=FNR} {x[$2] += $3} END {for(i=1; i<=cnt; ++i) print keys[i],x[keys[i]]}' freqdat044.dat freqdat045.dat freqdat046.dat freqdat047.dat freqdat049.dat freqdat050.dat
```

Comment: the first code changed the 2nd col ? i want the frequencies to stay the same -919.3 to -1036 and the second code gave a wrong answer because the sum for the first frequency should be 3 and i got 2 and the next 9 while i should get 12

Comment: @walaatamimi `x[$2]` is keeping track of the intermediate sums (indexed by the value of the second column).  Do you have sample data?

Comment: freqdat044.dat 0 -919.338782054983 0 0
1 -925.482700986468 2 1.4142135623731
2 -931.62676207503 0 0
3 -937.770965499483 0 0
4 -943.915310961806 0 0
5 -950.059798879229 0 0
6 -956.204428774916 1 1
7 -962.349201066099 0 0
8 -968.494115573965 0 0
9 -974.639172358118 1 1
10 -980.784371478163 1 1
11 -986.92971281489 0 0
12 -993.075196427904 0 0
13 -999.220822317206 0 0
14 -1005.36659066161 0 0
15 -1011.51250122269 0 0
16 -1017.65855411967 0 0
17 -1023.80474941214 1 1
18 -1029.9510869809 0 0
19 -1036.09756700476 0 0

Comment: i feel like one of the files is not added ? because when i tried with two files only it works

Comment: thanks Nirk ,we missed file freqdat048.dat , and please do you know if i want to insert the starting file name and the ending file name what i should do , like making a loop that imports freqdat0xy.dat to freqdat0XnYn.dat and to be limited to these files ?

Comment: +1 but you could simplify that second script a bit: `awk '{key[FNR]=$2; sum[FNR]+=$3} END {for(i=1; i in key; ++i) print key[i],sum[i]}'`

Comment: @EdMorton the reason I did it this way was because I didn't know if all of the files are ordered the same way.  If they are, then your simplification is fine

Comment: @walaatamimi if you want to do a loop, you can use shell expansion: `awk '...' freqdat0??.dat` matches `freqdat0xy`.  `?` matches any single character and `*` matches any number of characters.

Comment: if i used the * for freqdat0xy it will sum unwanted files that i don't want as the files from ffreqdat001 to freqdat099.dat and i normally want in the 40 -50 only

Comment: @walaatamimi you can also do `freqdat0{40..50}` (note: 2 dots, not 3)